# How do I disable multiselect functionality for the chips and allow only single select functionality?

Tags: flutter, flutter-chip

I have a chip class which allows me to select multiple chips and add them to a list of 'Selected chips'.
Now I want to disable multiselect and allow only single selection of chip at a time. When I select a chip the previously selected chip must revert back to the original appearance (before selection).

I tried replacing selected List with string so as to override the previously selected value. But this does things for the backend by sending only the latest selected value to the server. On the mobile app however I see all the chips I have selected. How do I achieve overall single select functionality. Any insights would be helpful, thanks in advance.
below is my code for the chip class:

```
class SelectableChips extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> titles;

  const SelectableChips({Key? key, required this.titles}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SelectableChipsState createState() => _SelectableChipsState();
}

class _SelectableChipsState extends State<SelectableChips> {
  List<String> selectedTitles = [];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Wrap(
      spacing: 4.0,
      children: widget.titles.map((title) {
        return ChoiceChip(
          label: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
            child: Text(
              title,
              style: TextStyle(
                color: selectedTitles.contains(title)
                    ? Colors.white
                    : const Color(0xFF52ACFF),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          selected: selectedTitles.contains(title),
          onSelected: (bool selected) {
            setState(() {
              if (selected) {
                selectedTitles.add(title);
              } else {
                selectedTitles.remove(title);
              }
            });
          },
          selectedColor: const Color(0xFF52ACFF),
          backgroundColor: const Color(0x3352ACFF),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
          ),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

TLDR: Disable multiselect and enable single select for the chips.